# Python+Flask+Cgi+Apache Rewrite?

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, cgi

I have a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9982120/344286) - I'm restricted to using 1and1 hosting, running cgi through virtualenv.

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +ExecCGI

DirectoryIndex index.cgi

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/mypath/test/index.cgi/(.*)$ - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^/mypath/test/(.*)$ /mypath/test/index.cgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

My `index.cgi` contains

```
#!/path/to/myenv/bin/python

from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", defaults={"path":''})
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def main(path):
    return "oh hai, mr. %s" % path


@app.route("/fnord")
def fnord():
    return "allo"

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

What I would like to be able to do is go to `www.mysite.com/mypath/test/page-one` and `www.mysite.com/mypath/test/page-two`. But right now all I can do is go to `index.cgi` or `index.cgi/fnord`. I can also go to `/test/`. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the leading slashes in your rule's patterns:

```
RewriteRule ^mypath/test/index.cgi/(.*)$ - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^mypath/test/(.*)$ /mypath/test/index.cgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The URI has the leading slash stripped off when applying rules inside an htaccess file.

You can also replace the `[S=1]` with simply `[L]`.

Comment: Ahah - this worked + placing the `.htaccess` file in the *root* folder of the webpage, i.e. `mv .htaccess ~/`